# How can i fix "this rom is for A5ulte, a5ultxx... your phone is" + CUSTOM ROM FOR SM-A500FU ANDROID PIE

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, rom

I have Resurrection remix 7.1.2 installed on my SM-A500fu and it worked perfectly. I have been using it for some time now till I recently discovered an upgrade of the same custom rom (resurrection remix 9.0 _android pie) for SM-A500FU. I downloaded and flashed through the right process. wipe cache, system etc.. When I try flashing the upgrade via twrp recovery, I keep getting an error message saying that the rom is meant for a5ulte, a5ultexx...it goes on to list other codenames...and at the latter part it says "my phone is" but doesn't state my phones codename.
I need help please.

Has my codename changed due to my previous ROM? 
how do I know my current codename because when I boot to the download mode, my phone's model is still SM-A500FU? 
Is there a way to work around it? please urgently.

mimbogel@gmail.com

Comment: check your phone model from download mode. edit your build.prop or default.prop with right phone model, or modify the installer script to skip the model check